# How to keep view state on navigation in GWT

Tags: gwt, view, navigation, state, gwtp

I'm developing app for my home server. It's dashboard with several pages such as cloud, admin, mediacenter. On each page I have an iframe where appropriate app is displayed, for cloud it's owncloud, for admin is webmin etc. What I want is to keep page state when I navigate to another, I mean when I'm doing sth in cloud page and I navigate to another page and after that I navigating back to cloud, I would like to see the same state as I when I leaved, how can I archieve it? I'm also using GWTP framework.

Comment: Have you gone through the [presenter lifecycle](https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP/wiki/Presenter-Lifecycle) document?

Comment: yes, I overrided onHide and OnReset and I'm not calling "super" in my methods, but it changes nothing, state is still lost on navigation

Comment: `onReset()` will always be called after the `onReveal()` method whenever you navigate to your presenter. onBind() method is called just once.

Comment: ok actually I researched that view state is kept, but not iframe state, iframe still refreshes itself on page change